# Laravel 5.3 trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-upgrade

I just updated my application into version 5.3 and in many routes I'm getting 
`trying to get property of non-object`
Like for example I have a resource called post and another called Article where each post can have one  Articles. And each Article has one writer.  When I do

```
$article->post->writer;
```

I get `trying to get property 'writer' of non-object`

Before updating from 5.2 this route as well as other routes worked perfectly.  Am i missing something here? should i do something after composer update has been run successfully?

Edit: The article, the post and the writer all exist in the DB. When I try to return $article I get this.

```
{
    "article": []
}
```

When i switch back to laravel 5.2 I get the proper article

Edit 2: it is routing bidnings problem. I'm using implicit model binding, so when i pass the ID of the article to my route, Laravel fetches the resource. but Now apparently it doesn't do it. I followed the instructions here for the bindings https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0 but Laravel can't still get the article

Comment: You article has no post, `$article->post` is `null`

Comment: As the error suggest, you are trying to get the `writer` property of something that is not an object. Likely to be null. 

Check your  "Article -> Post" relationship. If you can't find the issue, you should be positing more details

Comment: You should add your relations code too.

Answer (score 0):

It was name bindings issue. Laravel 5.3 needs some configuration in kernel.php as well as in the group route https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0
The group should have 'middleware' => ['bindings']